# Play Framework operation systems' requirements

Tags: playframework, debian

Can someone help to guide where can I find the operation systems' requirements for Play Framework?

I can't found anything on official docs.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a question really requires a community support.

Answer (score 0):

Play Framework doesn't have any strong requirement on the operating system as it's only a Java/Scala framework.

As long as you can run Java 8+ on your system, Play Framework will be just fine.

See also https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Requirements